# App crashes when the current location is on the geofence area

Tags: java, android, geofencing

I created an app that detects if the user is on the geofence area. But the problem is that when I enter the geofence area, the app closes.

Here is the code in *MainActivity.class*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String GEOFENCE_ID = "MyGeofenceId";
public static double lat = 1; //just some random coordinates
public static double lng = 1; //just some random coordinates
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = null;
private Button startLoc, startGeo, stopGeo;
private TextView txtPrint;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startLoc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startloc);
    startGeo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startgeo);
    stopGeo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopgeo);
    txtPrint = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPrint);

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                    txtPrint.append("Connected to GoogleApiClient");
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                    txtPrint.append("Suspended connection to GoogleApiClient");
                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    txtPrint.append("Failed to connect to GoogleApiClient" + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
                }
            })
            .build();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1234);
    }
}

public void setTextPrint(String text){
    txtPrint.setText(text);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    int response = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(response != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        txtPrint.append("Google Play Services not available - show dialog to ask user to download it");
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, response, 1).show();
    }else{
        txtPrint.append("Google Play Services is available - no action required");
    }
}

public void startLocationMonitoring(View view) {
    setTextPrint("startLoc");
    try{
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setInterval(10000)
                .setFastestInterval(5000)
                // .setNumUpdates(5)
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                txtPrint.append("Location update lat/long " + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
            }
        });
    }catch (SecurityException e){
        txtPrint.append("Security Exception - " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void startGeofenceMonitoring(View view) {
    txtPrint.append("startGeo");

    try{
        Geofence geofence = new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(GEOFENCE_ID)
                .setCircularRegion(lat, lng, 200)
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setNotificationResponsiveness(1000)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .build();

        GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest = new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
                .addGeofence(geofence).build();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        if(!googleApiClient.isConnected()){
            txtPrint.append("GoogleApiClient is not connected");
        }else{
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(googleApiClient, geofencingRequest, pendingIntent)
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                            if(status.isSuccess()){
                                txtPrint.append("Successfully added geofence");
                            }else{
                                txtPrint.append("Failed to add geofence - " + status.getStatus());
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }catch (SecurityException e){
        txtPrint.append("Security Exception - " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void stopGeofenceMonitoring(View view) {
    txtPrint.append("stopGeo");
    ArrayList<String> geofenceIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    geofenceIds.add(GEOFENCE_ID);
    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(googleApiClient, geofenceIds);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    googleApiClient.reconnect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}
}
```

The other class which contains the intent handler.  *GeofenceService.class*

```
public class GeofenceService extends IntentService {

public GeofenceService() {
    super("GeofenceService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    mainActivity.setTextPrint("HANDLED INTENT");
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if(geofencingEvent.hasError()){
        // handle error
    }else{

        int transition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
        List<Geofence> geofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();
        Geofence geofence = geofences.get(0);
        String requestId = geofence.getRequestId();

        if(transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER){
            mainActivity.setTextPrint("Entered Geofence");
        }else if(transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT){
            mainActivity.setTextPrint("Exited Geofence");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I also put the GeofenceService class in the Android Manifest

```
<service android:name=".GeofenceService" android:exported="true" 
 android:enabled="true"></service>
```

In the xml file there is 3 buttons which triggers the 
*startLocationMonitoring*, 
*startGeofenceMonitoring* and 
*stopGeofenceMonitoring*

The location is updating, I can add and remove a geofence. But when the current location is on the geofence area, the app closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
```

This is wrong. You can't create an activity like this. Moreover, you shouldn't do UI changes directly from your `IntentService`. What is the app isn't open? Then there is no activity.

What you should be doing is when the current location is in the geofence area, create a [Notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification). When the user clicks on the notification, open your activity by passing the **"HANDLED INTENT"** string in the intent, and then set this string to txtPrint.

Comment: I will do that thank you. But do you have any idea why the app force closes when the current location is in the geofence?

Comment: When you create an activity object, it doesn't call onCreate and the views are not initialized. So when you call setText, the textView is null and hence it crashes. Check your logs, you would see a null pointer exception

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you! @nupadhyaya